# Add css runtime to table row and data bind the row

Tags: jquery, css, knockout.js

I am really not sure how to solve. However i am quite close the solution and now just need one small help from you experts here. My working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq3ru/81/). When the page loads the 2 checkboxes are checked. My view is binded as below

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: dataOne">
    <tr  data-bind="css: { 'makeBold': $root.duplicates.indexOf(name1) !== -1 }" >
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td><td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-bind="text: display"></td><td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.duplicates.indexOf(name1) !== -1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My view model as below

```
var data1 = [{
name1: "one",
id: 1,
display: "Test1"
}, {
 name1: "two",
id: 2,
 display: "Test2"
}, {
name1: "three",
id: 3,
 display: "Test3"
}];
var data2 = [{
name2: "five"
}, {
name2: "two"
}, {
name2: "three"
}];

var viewModel = {
dataOne: ko.observableArray(data1),
dataTwo: ko.observableArray(data2),
duplicates: ko.observableArray()

};

 viewModel.dataTwo.push({
  name: "four"
  }); //add one on the end

  var flattenedOne = ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.dataOne(), function (item) {

     return item.name1;
   });

  var flattenedTwo = ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.dataTwo(), function (item) {

   return item.name2;
  });

  var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(flattenedOne, flattenedTwo);
    //return a flat list of differences
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(differences, function (difference) {
   if (difference.status === 'retained') {
      viewModel.duplicates.push(difference.value);
    }
   });
```

Now when user click on Update button it again load data and now 3 checkboxes are checked. What i am trying to achieve is

1. When user click on update button it should add css to table row and only make that row bold.
2. It should not check the checkbox as checked when user click's on update button.

So in our example when user click's on update button it should make row as bold but checkbox should not be checked. So only first row will be bold on clicking update button. Currently when page is loading it is making 2 rows bold and checked which is wrong. It should make row bold only clicking update button. Please help me guys.

Comment: you have same condition $root.duplicates.indexOf(name1) !== -1 for both css and checked binding

Comment: @NaveenKumar i realised it but dont know what should i do

Comment: Make separate condition for checked and css binding by adding new observable

Comment: @NaveenKumar can you please tell me how?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26850/discussion-between-naveenkumar-and-ashreva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem.

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarm/TaF8W/2/)

```
I have given separate condition using another observable .
```

Html :-

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: dataOne">
    <tr  data-bind="css: { 'makeBold': $root.duplicates.indexOf(name1) !== -1 }" >
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td><td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-bind="text: display"></td><td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.checkDuplicate.indexOf(name1) !== -1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.UpdateData"> Update </button>
```

Script:-

```
 var data1 = [{
  name1: "one",
  id: 1,
  display: "Test1"
 }, {
  name1: "two",
  id: 2,
  display: "Test2"
 }, {
  name1: "three",
  id: 3,
  display: "Test3"
 }];
var data2 = [{
  name2: "five"
 }, {
 name2: "two"
 }, {
  name2: "three"
 }];

var viewModel = {
 dataOne: ko.observableArray(data1),
 dataTwo: ko.observableArray(data2),
 duplicates: ko.observableArray(),
 checkDuplicate : ko.observableArray() // new observable to handle condition

};


viewModel.UpdateData = function(){
  data2 = [{
     name2: "one"
  }, {
     name2: "two"
  }, {
     name2: "three"
  }];

 viewModel.dataTwo(data2);

 var flattenedOne = ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.dataOne(), function (item) {

   return item.name1;
 });

 var flattenedTwo = ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.dataTwo(), function (item) {
   return item.name2;
 });

 var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(flattenedOne, flattenedTwo);
//return a flat list of differences
ko.utils.arrayForEach(differences, function (difference) {

  if (difference.status === 'retained' && viewModel.checkDuplicate().indexOf(difference.value) == -1 ) {
     viewModel.duplicates.push(difference.value);
  }
  });

};   


viewModel.dataTwo.push({
  name: "four"
 }); //add one on the end

 var flattenedOne = ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.dataOne(), function (item) {
  return item.name1;
 });

 var flattenedTwo = ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.dataTwo(), function (item) {
  return item.name2;
 });

  var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(flattenedOne, flattenedTwo);
   //return a flat list of differences
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(differences, function (difference) {
    if (difference.status === 'retained') {
      viewModel.checkDuplicate.push(difference.value);
    }
  });

 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: only first row will be bold and checkbox will not be checked. Check the question.

Comment: that is what i wanted. Requesting you to kindly update code instead of just fiddle as links are never permanent. Also easy for others to understand. Many thanks.