# loop through checkboxes and get data

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

This is in continuation from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610845/add-css-runtime-to-table-row-and-data-bind-the-row.)

You can see when the page is loaded it will show 2 selected items i.e two and three in the list. Now when i check the option Test1 it is not getting added in the list. In short its not adding newly selected item in the list. I have done following to loop through selected items

```
viewModel.selectedItems = ko.computed(function() {
debugger;
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.checkDuplicate(), function(id) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.dataOne(), function(item) {
            return item.name1 == id; 
        }); 
    });
});
```

I have put up fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/15/) so its easy to understand. Just forget about the Update button for the moment. When i select some checkbox it should display only those which are selected in the list below the update button. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> Now when i check the option Test1 it is not getting added in the list. In short its not adding newly selected item in the list......

I have created a fiddle in which list is updating according to the check/uncheck of checkboxes. Check this

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/17/)

*ViewModel*

```
function VM() {
    var self = this;   

    self.Checkboxes = ko.observableArray([
        new Checkbox("one", 1, "Test1"),
        new Checkbox("two", 2, "Test2", true),
        new Checkbox("three", 3, "Test3", true)
    ]);

    self.SelectedItems = ko.computed(function(){
        var boxes = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Checkboxes(), function(box){
            if(box.IsSelected()){
              boxes.push(box);
            }
        });
        return boxes;
    });
}
```

And let me know if it helps!

**Updated**

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5n5sX/1).

Comment: can you edit my fiddle. You are creating checkboxes at runtime. I am not so much confident with knockout. So it will really helpful if you edit my fiddle.

Comment: I am not doing anything different, the checkboxes created on the basis of `Checkboxes observableArray entries`, in your case you are also doing the same thing, your checkboxes are created with `dataone observableArray enrties`.

Comment: can you please modify my fiddle.

Comment: i tried but not sure how to make use of Isselected. See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/20/

Comment: The IsSelected property should associate with each checkbox object, so whenever you checked or unchecked any checkbox its associated property IsSelected will updates.

Comment: Please correct my updated fiddle. It is giving me error. I have posted that fiddle in my earlier comment

Comment: yes i saw your fiddle, you placed IsSelected property in your viewModel which is not needed, you need a Checkbox constructor which contains, check box associated properties like (id, display, name, IsSelected), i have created the same thing if you check my fiddle again you will get the concept and still if you have any query with my fiddle code that feel free to ask, i am not editing your fiddle because it contain lots of unnecessary complication which may not need and hard to understand your fiddle code logic

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27481/discussion-between-gaurav-and-ashreva)

Comment: i cant use your fiddle somehow. If its possible to change my fiddle then do it otherwise leave it. I am looking at some other possibilites. I am really sorry and thanks a ton for your efforts and valuable time you gave to such an idiot.